# Run some or all sections of an ant file

Tags: java, ant

Is there a way to specify an ANT file to run only one/some/all of its sections?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Split your build into appropriate [targets](http://ant.apache.org/manual/using.html#targets) so that you can call individual targets separately, and then you can specify the target you want to run from the command line.

Personally I like having "real" targets without any dependencies (which I can run independently) and then "fake" targets which are *just* dependent on the real ones, for convenience (e.g. "clean-build"). The alternative of having test depend on compile etc always ends up getting in the way for me :(

Comment: quick question: i use "ant -f filename" to run filename; how would i specify the target?

Answer (score 1):

You can group targets together using dependencies:

```
    <target name="A">
    <target name="B">
    <target name="C" depends="A,B">
```

runs
  A, B, then C.

You can also chain these to arbitrary depth. For example you could create an empty target "D" that depends on A, B which will only run A and B.

Answer (score 1):

```
<project....
    <target name="all">
       ...
    </target>
    <target name="some">
      ...
    </target>
</project>
```

run

```
ant all
```

or

```
ant some
```

Answer (score 1):

Define appropriate targets in your build file and then run

```
ant 'target name'
```

to run that particular one. You will have to configure target dependencies such that the ones you want to run separately can do so correctly.

It's a good practise to define these top-level targets with a description.

```
<target name="clean" description="Cleans up built artifacts">
```

Then you can run

```
ant -projecthelp
```

and this will display the targets with descriptions, thus telling you what targets are available. This will make life a lot easier further down the road, when you've forgotten what targets you've defined.